# Elastic Search Exact Match - wrong results

Tags: elasticsearch, search

I've done the following two searches according to tutorials and the official documentation from the ElasticSearch site but I'm getting more like a contains result other than an exact match. 
I'm very new to ES so excuse any noob mistakes. 
Any help would be appreciated.

According to the tutorials I've gone through so far this is not the case with their results. So I'm quite confused as to why I am getting the results I am.

Data Structure:

```
{
    "_scroll_id": "cXVlcnlBbmRGZXRjaDsxOzI3OlRsWmVmMGh5VENLR0FVclB3eXpIaVE7MDs=",
    "took": 7,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 16896,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "cus_index",
                "_type": "place",
                "_id": "71272349",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 34543,
                    "date1": "1928-09-13 00:00:00",
                    "date2": "1929-01-01 00:00:00",
                    "code": "1000",
                    "phrase": "GOD MODE",
                    "boolCol": false
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "cus_index",
                "_type": "place",
                "_id": "71272349",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 78635,
                    "date1": "1928-09-13 00:00:00",
                    "date2": "1929-01-01 00:00:00",
                    "code": "3000",
                    "phrase": "THANK GOD",
                    "boolCol": false
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "cus_index",
                "_type": "place",
                "_id": "71272349",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "id": 45645,
                    "date1": "1928-09-13 00:00:00",
                    "date2": "1929-01-01 00:00:00",
                    "code": "5000",
                    "phrase": "SOME OTHER GOD PHRASE",
                    "boolCol": false
                }
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

Queries:

```
// returns all rows
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "match" : {
                    "phrase": "GOD MODE"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// this returns all rows
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "GOD MODE",
            "fields": ["phrase"]
        }
    }
}

// this returns no rows
{
    "query" : {
        "term": {
            "phrase": "GOD MODE"
        }
    }
}
```

Mappings:

```
{
    "cus_index": {
        "aliases": {},
        "mappings": {
            "place": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "int"
                    },
                    "date1": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "date2": {
                        "type": "date"
                    },
                    "code": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    // this is the important one
                    // i just guessed the others as this is an example, But the col in qu is a string
                    "phrase": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "boolCol": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "creation_date": "1545321229864",
                "number_of_shards": "1",
                "number_of_replicas": "0",
                "uuid": "4PpzZ49SQZWDDW8sawOIaA",
                "version": {
                    "created": "2030199"
                }
            }
        },
        "warmers": {}
    }
}
```

ES Version:

```
{
    "name": "Test Node",
    "cluster_name": "firsttestnode",
    "version": {
        // this was a very old version latest "6.5.4" this is what i 
        // should have been using for the answers below to work.
        "number": "2.3.1",
        "build_hash": "bd980929010aef404e7cb0843e61d0665269fc39",
        "build_timestamp": "2016-04-04T12:25:05Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "5.5.0"
    },
    "tagline": "Test tag line"
}
```

---------------------- Answer Attempts -----------------------------------

I PUT and POST to the following body to the given Url below and got the following errors:

```
// URL: http://ip_address:9200/test_index1

{
  "mappings": {
    "demo":{
       "properties": {
          "phrase": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "phrase1": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
       }
    }
  }
}

// errors
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                "reason": "No handler for type [keyword] declared on field [phrase1]"
            }
        ],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [demo]: No handler for type [keyword] declared on field [phrase1]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "No handler for type [keyword] declared on field [phrase1]"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

both of the answers below are working as expected. 
Thanks to both. Not really sure to answer correct, But to other reading this I would recommend both.

Only thing is in answer 1 the '"type": "string"' should be '"type": "text"' for the example to just work.

Comment: Also add the mapping of your index to the question.

Comment: Sorry im not sure how to add mapping. This is my first time using ES

Comment: My bad. in the Kibana give - GET /your_index_name will give you the mapping in JSON format

Comment: I've updated my question to show the mappings

Comment: @TheMan68- What is your ES version

Comment: please see edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to update the phrase property as below:

```
"phrase": {
   "type": "text",
   "fields": {
      "keyword": {
         "type": "keyword"
      }
   }
}
```

In the above case when indexing document you only need to pass the value to `phrase` field and `phrase.keyword` gets auto-indexed.

Whenever you want to do exact match you can use term query as below:

```
{
   "term": {
      "phrase.keyword": "some text"
   }
}
```

Comment: HI there. This doesn't seem to work as expected. I don't suppose you could write a minimal example of how to make an index as follows url/anIndex/entry

With the columns body

thank you for your help

Comment: I went with this structure as the answer as i would recommend the phrase.keyword structure as well. but the "type": "string" has to be changed to "type":"text" to work for me

Comment: Yes it should be `text` and not `string`.  Thanks for pointing out. I corrected my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot mate. both you and the answer below was hard to choose from. Your were both great help

Answer (score 0):

The `term` query finds documents that contain the **exact term specified in the inverted index**.

**TL;DR:**

Example:

```
PUT test_index1
{
  "mappings": {
    "demo":{
       "properties": {
          "phrase": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "phrase1": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
       }
    }
  }
}


POST test_index1/demo/1
{
  "phrase":"GOOD GOD",
  "phrase1":"GOOD GOD"
}

GET  test_index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "phrase": "GOOD"
    }
  }
}
```

above returned result

```
GET  test_index1/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "phrase1": "GOOD"
    }
  }
}
```

above does not return result

You can even use `_analyze`

```
GET  test_index1/_analyze
{
  "field": "phrase",
  "text": ["GOOD GOD"]
}
```

to see how the the documented is stored in inverted index.

**To answer your question:**

Term query look for `exact match`.Since your phrase type is String, The word GOD MODE is stored as GOD and MODE, where the term query will do exact match with GOD MODE. Either you have to change it to `Keyword` or use `match` query

Comment: whats an inverted index?

Comment: @TheMan68 - it is a index concept using which the documents are stored

Comment: Hi there. Thank you very much. Regarding why I was getting those results then that was a really helpful walk through. My next question word be I need to be able to match these brases on a "phrase = val OR phrase = val2 OR phrase = val3" the exact has to be compatible with wildcard searches also. So which would be the best way to store them? If I store them as keywords is that possible? And I already tried match phrase and it still gave me all the results

Comment: i would say you you can use field type to store exact and Text to store the indexed document.

Comment: please see answer for errors that im getting when I do a post with what you recommended

Comment: What is the version of your elasticsearch?